# Sort the date in Sqlite database

Tags: iphone

I am making an iPhone application in which I am storing date and time in a column now I want to sort the date and time in the order which occurs first.

How can I do this? please give me some solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save the `NSDate` as `NSTimeInterval`:

```
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
```

The `NSTimeInterval` is just a `double` which you can save in the a SQLite database.

With an simple SQL query you can then select the sort then:

```
SELECT * FROM dateTable ORDER BY myDateColumn DESC
```

And to get the `NSDate` back just:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:databaseTimeInterval];
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE DateColumn >= date('now') ORDER BY DateColumn ASC
```