# Sort the date in database column of sqlite

Tags: iphone, database

I am making an iPhone app. In this app i am using sqlite database for storing the dates in the column. [image] The date which I am storing in the database column is not in the sorting order as you can see in the image. Now I want to sort the date according to ascending order. How can I do this. Please provide me some solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you define the column as a `date` to SQLite?  SQLite knows how to sort dates if you simply tell it they're present.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161313/sort-the-date-in-sqlite-database

Comment: Yup, I have metioned it as datetime

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the datetime in timestamp format and then try to sort them.