# Sqlite3 date is not sorting ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sorting, sqlite

i am creating app with sqlite database, i have table event

`CREATE TABLE "Events" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL , "Date" DATETIME, "Title" TEXT, "ImgUrl" TEXT)`

where i have taken Date as **DATETIME**, i want table data sorted on date , but it is not giving me sorted data,

I have tried in SQLITE MANAGER but here also it is not shows properly sorted data.

[image]

**EDIT**
Sorting in Sqlite manager click on Date column. still not getting sorted data.
[image]

[image]

Comment: @Reformer:  Why downvoting.?? please explain.

Comment: @Reformer: i know how to use it with sqlite mgr. firfox plugin,when i click on date it also not give sorted date., check updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your query is sorting with your `Date` column lexicographically as though the type is text. You might prefer an integral type. Your options include:

> 1.2 Date and Time Datatype
>
> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates
>   and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite
>   are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER
>   values:
>
> TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS"). REAL as Julian
>   day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November
>   24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar. INTEGER
>   as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.
>   Applications can chose to store dates and times in any of these
>   formats and freely convert between formats using the built-in date and
>   time functions.

See [here](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

Comment: so why it is show DATETIME type when i am creating table if it  doesnt support,?

Comment: Thanks , i have updated table and store date as **'yyyy-mm-dd'** format.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite doesn't have `DATETime` type, the result is because it's using varchar sort.

http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

this is a workable solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/7161459/94962

Comment: Thnks for replay, but when creating table it shows column type `DATETIME`.

Answer (score 0):

Here you got a sorted result but it's by day of the month does not date as you expected.The SQLite sort date in the format of 'YYYY-mm-dd', if you have the date which is not in the form of 'YYYY-mm-dd', convert to this format.
Modify your query as

SELECT * FROM Events ORDER BY (substr(Date, 10, 7) || '-' || substr(Date, 5, 4) || '-' || substr(Date, 1, 2));

Hope this will help you.